# Can't send anything to spawned Erlang process

Tags: erlang, actor, erlang-escript

I have the following Erlang code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -pz ../deps/amqp_client ../deps/rabbit_common ../deps/amqp_client/ebin ../deps/rabbit_common/ebin

% RMQ module
-module(rmq).
-export([main/1, send/1, validate/0, test/0]).
-include_lib("../deps/amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").

main(_) ->
    %send(<<"test_esio">>),
    %validate(),
    Pid = spawn(rmq, test, []),
    % Pid = spawn(fun() -> test() end), <= I've tried this way too
    Pid ! s.

test() ->
    receive
        s ->
            io:format("BAR ~n"),
            send(<<"esio">>),
            test();
        get ->
            validate(),
            test();
        _ ->
            io:format("FOO"),
            test()
    end.
```

I run this with:
    `excript rmq.erl`

This code doesn't work. Looks like spawn doesn't work.

Rest of my code works, function send and validate works correctly if I run it from main (I've commented its). What I'm doing wrong?

Sorry, maybe it's a dumb question but I'm a beginner with erlang. I've tried search answer in internet and books and I failed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not actually in spawn, but in module/escript confusion.

In few words, escript file are not really modules, not from point of Erlang VM, even if you use `-module()` directive.  They are interpreted, and not compiled at all, and definitely they can not be called by module like "rmq:test()", or in you case trough dynamic module call by `spawn`.

Easiest solution is separate script from actual modules. In your `rmq.es` you would just start some proper module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -pz ../deps/amqp_client ../deps/rabbit_common ../deps/amqp_client/ebin ../deps/rabbit_common/ebin

main(_) ->
  rmq:start().
```

And there in module `rmq.erl`:

```
-module(rmq).
-export([start/0, send/1, validate/0, test/0]).
-include_lib("../deps/amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").

start() ->
    Pid = spawn(rmq, test, []),

    %% Pid = spawn(?MODULE, test, []),  %% works with macro too

    %% Pid = spawn(fun() -> test() end), <= I've tried this way too
    Pid ! s.

test() ->
    receive
        s ->
            io:format("BAR ~n"),
            send(<<"esio">>),
            test();
        get ->
            validate(),
            test();
        _ ->
            io:format("FOO"),
            test()
    end.
```

Or you could just start this module without escript, with `-run` flag like this

```
erl -pz deps/*/ebin -run rmq start
```

---

**EDIT** regarding compilation problems

You compile your modules with [`erlc` command](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html). To just compile use `erlc rmq.erl`, which will produce `rmq.beam` file in current directory. But convention is to keep all your source files in `src` directory, all compiled files in `ebin` direcory, and things like run-scripts could be placed in the top directory. Something like that:

```
project
|-- ebin
|   |-- rmq.beam
|
|-- src
|   |-- rmq.erl
|
|-- rmq.es
```

Assuming that you run all your shell commands form `project` directory, to compile all file from `src` and place `.beam` binaries in `ebin` use `erlc src/rmq.erl -o ebin`, or `erlc src/* -o ebin`  In documentation you can find you explanation of `-o` flag"

> **-o directory**
>
> The directory where the compiler should place the output files. If not specified, output files will be placed in the current working directory.

Then, after compilation you can run your code, either with [`erl` Erlang VM](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) or using `escript` (which kind-off uses `erl`.

`erl` to runs code from compiled modules, and to do that he needs to be able to locate those compiled `*.ebin` binaries.  For this he uses code path, which is the list of directors in which he will search for those files.  This list automatically consist standard library directories, and of course you can add to it directories with your own code with use of `-pa` flag.

> -pa Dir1 Dir2 ...
>
> Adds the specified directories to the beginning of the code path, similar to code:add_pathsa/1. See code(3). As an alternative to -pa, if several directories are to be prepended to the code and the directories have a common parent directory, that parent directory could be specified in the ERL_LIBS environment variable. See code(3).

In your case it would be `erl -pa ebin`, or to include binaries of all deps you can use `erl -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin`.

Exactly same options are used in second line of your escript. With exception of `*` character, which will not be expand like it would be in the shell.  In escript you have to provide paths to each dependency separately.  But the idea of including `-pa ebin` stays exactly the same.

To automate and standardize this process tools like [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar) and [erlang.mk](https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk) where created (I would recommend the later).  Using those should help you a little with your workflow.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, but I still have a problem.

escript: exception error: undefined function rmq:start/0

Comment: Check if `rmq.erl` module compiled to `rmq.beam` without errors.  And make sure directory with binary is in `erl` path (with `-pa DIR` or `-pz DIR`).

Comment: I compile with: erlc -pa deps/*/ebin rmq.erl and got compilation error: File has no extension: /home/esio/work/stacja/src/deps/rabbit_common/ebin

Why compilation doesn't work if i use erlc and works if I use escript?

Comment: Extended my answer with some explenation between `erlc` and `erl`, and where to use which flags.

Comment: Thank you for a explamation, but my problem is different, I can run my erlang script from question, but I can't compile... :/

Erlang compiler can't recognize my rabbitmq dependencies... :/ I think this is other problem than my question...

Comment: Ye. You (and I fallowed) use `-include_lib()` directive, which can fail silently (and have different porpuse). Try using `-include()`.  And rather than providing full path to `.hrl` directory in your module you could use `-I` during compilation.  And I do encourage you to ask new questions.  You can than provide more description to what and why is failing (without any error message I'm just guessing , based on your guess).

Comment: I've created project with rebar and everything works for me. :)